# wix/React-Native-Navigation blank screen in the beginning

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, velo

**Issue Description**

Whenever I try to launch App, a blank screen appears for close to 1 sec, then it animates to project screen. Can I bypass the splash screen completely.

**Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots**

Default setup as shown in documentation.. https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android

I have published the app for you to see.. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.billcalc&hl=en

**Tried Solution**

As in this [issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2358), i tried adding background image in the app. But, the problem persists.

**Environment**

```
React Native Navigation version: "^1.1.300"
React Native version: "0.50.4"
Platform: Android (iOS not tested)
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Both Debug and Release
```

Comment: Happens the same on mine, any idea? Were you able to solve it?

Comment: See the reply in this [github issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2358). There are ways to implement it, but I myself haven't looked into them. I quickly switched to [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and have been using this library since.

Comment: Is it better? I should consider it

Comment: Well, it hasn't given me any problem till now. Also we don't need to edit android/ios's files. In that case it is better.